# struct file_operations vs struct vnodeops

Tags: files, filesystems, linux-kernel, inode, vfs

As per my understanding kernel maintains 4 tables.

1. Per process FD table.
2. System wide open file table `struct file`
3. Inode (in-memory) table `struct vnode`
4. Inode (on-disk) table.

`struct file` have one field named `struct file_operations f_ops;` which contains FS specific operations like `ext2_read()`, `ext2_write();`

`struct vnode` also have one field `struct vnodeops v_op;` which contains FS specific operations too.

My question is why we have similar functionalities inside both? Or am I getting something wrong?
Are things different in Unix and Linux? Because I did not find `struct vnode` inside Linux's fs.h

Reference: https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/wcbrown/courses/IC221/classes/L09/Class.html

Diagram (from "Unix internals new frontiers" book)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have found the answer.

In previous versions of Unix like SVR4, `struct file` does not contain `file_operations` field and all operations e.g. read, write etc. contained by `vnode->v_op`.

However, in case of Linux `struct file` will contain `file_operations` field which will have functions like open, read, write etc. and `struct inode` (similar to vnode) will contain `inode_operations` field which will have operations like lookup, link, unlink, symlink, rmdir, mkdir, rename, etc.